# How do I mention a role with Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, mention

I am making a bot and I am trying to Ping a certain role.  Here is the relevant code:

```
let msga = msg.author;
msg.channel.send("@NES Found one!! " + msga);
```

@NES is the role I am trying to ping/mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Just add an opening and closing angle bracket and use the role id to make the mention.</s>

```
msg.channel.send("<@id> Found one!! " + msga);
```

This answer was valid for older versions of discord.js (I believe v11 and under) but is now invalid for v12+ use yummypasta's solution for the newer versions.

Answer (score 41):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58749539/4699945) is incorrect. You ping a *user* with `<@id>`, not a *role*.

As stated in [this Github issue](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/459#issuecomment-231543385), for roles, you have to use `<@&id>` and the role has to be pingable.

So, the correct code for the question would be something like:

```js
msg.channel.send("<@&" + roleId + "> Found one!! " + msga);
```

Or, using fancy formatted strings:

```js
msg.channel.send(`<@&${roleId}> Found one!! ${msga}`);
```

Comment: Correct answer but you have a space after the **&** and before the **"** which shouldn't be there in your first block of code. It should be: msg.channel.send("<@&" + roleId + "> Found one!! " + msga);

Comment: My answer was correct at the time of posting, before v12 was released, updated my answer to point to this one.

Answer (score 2):

It is:

```
 message.channel.send(`<@& id >`);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:
`` msg.channel.send(`<@&${'roleId'}> Found one!! ${msga}`); ``